# How to clean an E: drive (new Recovery drive since Windows 10 1803) on HP laptop

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, windows-10-v1803

I started getting warnings about running out of space on my E: drive. 
I've read many articles, threads and posts online about how to clean the drive but none of them resolved my issue.

My machine specs:

OS: Win 10 Pro

Version: 1803

OS build: 17134.1

I disabled hiding of protected/system files to see what's on the E: drive but I don't see any clutter. I ran the disk clean up several time as an admin to no avail. Any tips and suggestions how to clean up the E: drive would be much appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean clean it? That is your recovery partition, it shouldn't be used for anything by you... Don't mess with it at all. Or format it and realize you won't be able to "reset" or restore Windows without downloading a USB image and likely a multitude of drivers as well.

Comment: As a system recovery partition, the total size and the free space seems normally. I am not recommend to clean disk on E, also it will not save much space than existing status based on the recovery contents size. The main issue you are facing is on C drive. It too large, we could use the free space to create another drive. Try to go to Disk Management console, and check if it is available to shrink disk to create another drive.

Comment: Please adjust the title of this question as this is about a drive that is created due to Windows updates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a new OEM recovery drive that gets created during Windows 10 v1803 upgrade. You can [fix the issue by removing the drive letter for the drive](https://borncity.com/win/2018/05/02/windows-10-v1803-update-creates-a-new-oem-partition/)

- Open cmd.exe as admin
- run the following commands :

> ```
> diskpart
> list volume
> select volume <number of the OEM recovery drive>
> remove letter=<letter of the OEM recovery drive>
> exit
> ```