# Windows 10 after restoring the system from an image in a recovery partition, assigns it a letter

Tags: windows-10, diskpart, recovery-partition

The problem is that after restoring the PC from a disk image, I am able to see the recovery partition (with ID 27) in "This PC", which should not happen. Before restoring the PC I have removed the drive letter to the recovery partition with DISKPART.
The question is: how do I prevent Windows from reassigning a letter to the recovery partition after restoring the PC from disk image?

Edit:

I have Windows 10 (64-bit) version 1903 (May 2019 Update) (clean install).

I don't want to have to remove the drive letter after the restore, I want instead that Windows doesn't assign it after the restore.

I have a MBR disk with an Standard BIOS that even in the last supported update doesn't implement the support for GPT disks. In any case, I could only convert basic MBR disks without any partitions or volumes into a GPT disk, making data backup operations difficult.

The GUID method doesn't work because i have an MBR disk.

```
SET ID=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
```

and therefore neither:

```
gpt attributes=0x8000000000000001
```

For me works only:

```
attributes volume set nodefaultdriveletter
```

But in this case Windows 10 continues to assign a drive letter to the recovery partition after the system restore, therefore it doesn't have the desired effects.

I have used the Windows 10 built-in "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" to create the image only of the "C" partition and for the restore I have used the procedure on the Windows 10 version 1903 (May 2019 Update) installation CD downloaded from the official website. I don't think that this procedure changes the attributes of the recovery partition but I can't verify it with DISKPART because I don't have a GPT disk but I was able to verify that the "nodefaultdriveletter" attribute is remained even after that the system was restored, however Windows has anyway reassigned the drive letter to the recovery partition.

I backed up on the recovery partition when it still had a letter, otherwise it wouldn't have been seen by the Windows 10 utility "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)".

In my MBR disk I have tested that a logical recovery partition that is located within of an extended partition and a primary recovery partition have the same behavior.

Last edit:

The startup task method may not always work because the volume number of the recovery partition can change depending on the devices connected at the time of the restore and is also useless to identify a volume based on some features, because there can be multiple volumes with the same characteristics and volumes can have the same label even within of a single disk. Since I have an MBR disk, the partitions cannot be uniquely identified thanks to the GUID. In other words, this isn't the solution.
I have read the release notes of the BIOS updates for my motherboard on the official Fujitsu website and none of the updates have GPT disk support implemented. The latest BIOS version supported by my motherboard (FUJITSU D3011-A1) is the V6.00 Release R1.06.3011.A1 (Phoenix SecureCore(tm) Setup Utility).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clean an E: drive (new Recovery drive since Windows 10 1803) on HP laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1319266/how-to-clean-an-e-drive-new-recovery-drive-since-windows-10-1803-on-hp-laptop)

Comment: How you prevent it would require you to change the attributes of the driver to remove the flag that caused a drive letter to be assigned to the recovery partition

Comment: With diskmanagement you can remove the letter only to partitions with ID = 07 and in any case with DISKPART you get the same result, but this is not the point. I don't want to have to remove the drive letter after the restore, I want instead that Windows doesn't assign it after the restore.

Comment: @Ramhound How?.

Comment: You can't restore a system image selectively. The most you can do is add a startup task that will run once, do the job, then erase itself.

Comment: You have to use DISKPART to remove the attribute.  You shouldn't even have to remove the drive letter from a recovery partition, the default attributes should prevent the partition from having a drive letter assigned to it.  The only time it happens is if the attributes are changed on a recovery partition.  Whatever program you used to recover the image of the partition must not be restoring the partition attributes.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1370499/how-do-i-know-that-a-drive-that-is-not-labelled-recovery-is-actually-the-recov/1370578#1370578

Comment: @harrymc this is the last way.

Comment: Should be easy enough with RunOnce.

Comment: Thank'you @Ramhound for edited my answer. Please be patient for my grammar of English, I am italian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I backed up on the recovery partition when it still had a letter, otherwise, it wouldn't have been seen by the Windows 10 utility "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)".

I backed up to a different partition than the recovery one, so I could remove the letter to the recovery partition before backing up. After that I reassigned a letter to the recovery partition to be able to move the backup inside, coming from another partition.

I have then removed the letter again and tried to restore it!  It worked, the letter was not reassigned to the recovery partition after the restore!  I have also verified that after backing up the C drive if you remove or add any partitions, the restore cannot work.

From this I deduce that even making a single partition backup, this backup has the memory of the number of partitions and of the letter assigned to each of them, even if it doesn't restore the label on all the volumes but only on those to which it was backed up.

This method not only doesn't reassign the letter to the recovery partition, but I have also verified that if I had not done this step:

> I have then removed the letter again

after the restore, Windows 10 would have removed it. This method also works for GPT disks.

It is good practice to set the recovery partition with id=27 using DISKPART, to mark it as such and prevent the less experienced user from formatting it or removing it through Disk Management.